# Onblur giving continuous alert in loop when clicked from 1 textbox to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, onblur

I am currently calling an on blur function for all textboxes,like below:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="fname2" onblur="myFunction()">
```

which validates the input provided and gives an alert in case of mismatch. The issue I am facing here is When the user blurs from 1 textbox and directly focusing to another checkbox. The Alert continuously apprears. because it considers the click of ok of the alert as a blur of the textbox.
I could use onchange. But onchange is giving me an issue in IE.
I have duplicated a sample code here:

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("Value Changed");
}
```

```html
Enter your name:
<input type="text" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="fname2" onblur="myFunction()">
<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>
```

Comment: Your sample code seems to be working fine to me. What do you expect?

Comment: when the alert window pops up the window focuses on the alert window rather than the input, which causes it to be fired multiple times when you click from input to input, if you use `console.log()` you can see it only fires once.

Comment: But i need to ask a confirmation from the user here. so console.log() will not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `alert` (or its cousins `confirm` and `prompt`) in `blur` or `focus` events. Their odd 1990's focus-stealing, world-stopping behavior and its interplay with the `blur` and `focus` events varies from browser to browser.

Use a modern mechanism for displaying the message via the DOM, rather than `alert`.

In a comment you've said:

> But i need to ask a confirmation from the user here...

There are lots of ways to do that within the DOM. You can either code them yourself or use any of several libraries that do a lot of the heavy-lifting for you.

Comment: Thanks!. I have used a library to do the job for me :)